# should we avoid synchronous I/O calls in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, asynchronous, architecture

As Node.js is single threaded, event driven architecture, is it okay to make synchronous I/O calls or should we always make use of callbacks, promises to fetch the data?

Comment: What database even offers synchronous DB calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in node js you NEVER find a good you case to prefer synchronous use cases. The good choice is always Promise/async await, just for the single thread structure of the runtime (as rightly said by you).

Answer (score 0):

If your program is a server intended to serve multiple requests, then you should not use ANY synchronous I/O anywhere except in startup or shutdown code because doing so will ruin the scalability of your server by blocking the one and only thread that runs your Javascript forcing all requests to be handled serially, one at a time instead of multiple requests being worked on at once.

This could literally be a 100x sacrifice in scalability.